# Confusion about fundamental assumption of statistical mechanics

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I am confused about the fundamental assumption of statistical mechanics. It says, over a long time scale, that all microstates are equally accessible. I get it so far.

But for microstate, there are arrangements such that no particles(thinking of Einstein solid) have energy (Daniel schroeder), how is that physically possible? and how does it make sense with fundamental assumption of statistical mechanics?

BR

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking if the set of available Microstates is constrained by energy conservation?